# ¿Se puede hacer un .caption responsive?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando aplicar un script de cuenta atrás en una imagen. El problema es que cuando le doy estilo me confundo un poco.

Si le aplico el estilo con `#demo`, se aplica correctamente, pero el `.caption` (texto de la imagen) se desborda.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {

  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contenido {
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-top: 7px;
 text-align: center;
}

.lateral {
  background-color: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnas), 1fr);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 1200px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid__item {
  padding-top: 85%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid__img {
  --object-fit: cover;
  --object-position: center center;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: var(--object-fit);
  object-position: var(--object-position);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid__img,
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:599px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 1;
  }
}

.caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#demo {
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="contenido"> 

 <div style="flex-grow: 2">
    <p class="lateral">
    Gatos gatitos <br>
    Gatos de prueba <br>
    Vivan los gatos
    </p>       
  </div>
    
 <div style="flex-grow: 8"> 
    
  <div class="grid">
    
      <div class="grid__item">
      
        <img  class="grid__img" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg" alt="">
    
         <div class="caption">
          <p id="demo"></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 7, 2020 14:40:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Revisa la sección correspondiente";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

Si esto se ve desde una pantalla grande, se visualiza bien, el problema ocurre en pantallas pequeñas/minimizadas.

Quisiera saber si se puede ajustar el `.caption` (junto con el `#demo`) a la imagen según las dimensiones de la pantalla.

La imagen se redimensiona bien, pero el texto no.

> Nota: No podré probarlo hasta el lunes, por si no respondo lo que
>   funciona o no el fin de semana. Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Lo estoy viendo en distintas pantallas y no se desborda nunca. Podrías adjuntar una imagen con el desborde que ves tú?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir a `.caption` un `max-height: 100%` para evitar que exceda el tamaño de su padre.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: none;
}

.flex-container > div {

  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contenido {
 background-color: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-top: 7px;
 text-align: center;
}

.lateral {
  background-color: rgba(236, 223, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnas), 1fr);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 1200px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid__item {
  padding-top: 85%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid__img {
  --object-fit: cover;
  --object-position: center center;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: var(--object-fit);
  object-position: var(--object-position);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid__img,
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width:599px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .grid {
    --columnas: 1;
  }
}

.caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#demo {
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="contenido"> 

 <div style="flex-grow: 2">
    <p class="lateral">
    Gatos gatitos <br>
    Gatos de prueba <br>
    Vivan los gatos
    </p>       
  </div>
    
 <div style="flex-grow: 8"> 
    
  <div class="grid">
    
      <div class="grid__item">
      
        <img  class="grid__img" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/410/cpsprodpb/8536/production/_103520143_gettyimages-908714708.jpg" alt="">
    
         <div class="caption">
          <p id="demo"></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 7, 2020 14:40:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Revisa la sección correspondiente";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```